# Error installing fbprophet on Google Cloud Platform AI Platform

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, facebook-prophet, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to install facebook prophet on my Jupyter Notebook in AI Platform

```
!pip3 install fbprophet
```

I am getting this error:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting fbprophet
  Using cached fbprophet-0.7.1.tar.gz (64 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.22 in /home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from fbprophet) (0.29.21)
Collecting cmdstanpy==0.9.5
  Using cached cmdstanpy-0.9.5-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pystan>=2.14 in /home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from fbprophet) (2.19.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in /home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from fbprophet) (1.18.5)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas>=1.0.4 (from fbprophet) (from versions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0, 0.3.0b2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0rc1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0rc2, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0rc1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0rc1, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0rc2, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0rc1, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0rc0, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.25.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas>=1.0.4 (from fbprophet)
```

It says that my pandas is not >= 1.0.4
When I try to upgrade my pandas the latest version is '0.25.3'. It might be to do with the deprecation warning of python 3.5

I have researched trying to upgrade my Python in AI platform before and the process seems complicated. Does anyone know a workaround? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to create a new instance ? !python -V Python 3.7.8. Recent versions already use Python 3.7

Comment: It looks like it's working. I'll update you. Thank you!!

Comment: You are a life saver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a new instance which has Python 3.7 then install fbprophet

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1775

Solution:

```
pip install pystan==2.18.0.0

pip install fbprophet
```

After, I did these 2 simple steps, I got no red errors and ready to predict the future with FB Prophet :D